# Composer Could not find package jwt-auth

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php, jwt

I'm trying to add `jwt-auth` to my Symfony project.

trying to execute the below command

```
$ composer require jwt-auth
```

getting these error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package jwt-auth.
    Did you mean one of these?
      tymon/jwt-auth
      tuupola/slim-jwt-auth
      auth0/jwt-auth-bundle
      admad/cakephp-jwt-auth
      dmkit/phalcon-jwt-auth`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: composer packages always consist of a namespace and a package name in the format `namespace/name`. Therefore `jwt-auth` is not a valid package. You're likely looking to require `tymon/jwt-auth`

Comment: @Padarom I'm new to Symfony and following  this link 
 http://slides.com/allucardster/jwt-based-authentication-with-symfony#/16 to implement, but here they mentioned `composer require jwt-auth` is the package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing:

```
composer require jwt-auth
```

Is equivalent to doing:

```
composer require lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle
```

In order to be able to use the short-hand version, you need to have Flex installed in your Symfony project. Basically, Flex is a Composer plugin to automate certain configuration tasks after a bundle is installed, like creating the configuration files, updating the `.env` file... Have a read here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html

You can totally just use the second command if you don't want to install Flex in your Symfony project.

The currently supported recipes are all available here: https://github.com/symfony/recipes. As you can see here: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/2.5/manifest.json#L8 lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle can be automatically installed by using it's alias: `jwt-auth`.